# The offset a number of records after insert(MongoDB)

Tags: algorithm, scala

i faced with the small problem. I should offset some of the records after insert. Small Example :

Notes:
My table has a next structure. {Id : Long, priority : Int}

Current state of table:

```
{Id: 103, name:"Task #1", description:"text", priority: 1}
{Id: 641, name:"Task #2", description:"text", priority: 2}
{Id: 2225, name:"Task #3", description:"text", priority: 3}
{Id: 7741, name:"Task #4", description:"text", priority: 4}
```

Step#1
Insert new document, {Id: 8888, name:"Task #5", description:"text", priority: 2}.

state after insert operation:(priority is unique field and we should offset previous documents)

```
{Id: 103, name:"Task #1", description:"text", priority: 1}
{Id: 8888, name:"Task #5", description:"text", priority: 2}
{Id: 641, name:"Task #2", description:"text", priority: 3}
{Id: 2225, name:"Task #3", description:"text", priority: 4}
{Id: 7741, name:"Task #4", description:"text", priority: 5}
```

The only method I found was a mass update.Do you know another method\mechanism to implement that operation?(I can change table structure or perform some operation with record on code)

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. If you want some offset on your ids, in the subsequent insert you can increase the id value.

Comment: The main problem is related to the field "priority". When i insert new document i should update part of previous documents(Priority must have unique value). Was inserted new document with priority = 2, after that i should offset document with same priority (2 -> 3) and so on. I did it use mass update, but maybe you know another method

Comment: The rules are as follows, the priority must be unique, if was inserted already exist value, then we must shift the previous values.(Priority is part of full object)

Comment: Was added more complete example.))